# Idiomatic way to convert a Twitter Future[False] to an exceptional Future?

Tags: scala, future

I want to convert a Twitter Future[Boolean] that is false to an exceptional Future.

One way to do this would be to filter and then pass a PartialFunction to `rescue`:

```
theFuture
  .filter(b => b) // if b is false, becomes exceptional
  .rescue {
     case Try.PredicateDoesNotObtain 
           => Future.exception(new MyPreferredExceptionType())
  }
```

Another way would be to flatMap:

```
theFuture
  .flatMap(b => if (b) Future.value(b) else Future.exception(new MyPreferredExceptionType())
```

But both ways seem awkward and un-idiomatic. Suggestions?

Comment: why can't you just do theFuture.map{case true => `do Something` ; case false=> CustomeException("message")}

Comment: Your `flatMap` version looks completely reasonable to me.

Comment: Raman: that would make it a non-exceptional Future of an Exception. Throwing in the map would however work.